# Find the usual time when the cpu utilisation is High in a CPU performance dataset

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a cpu performance dataset in the following format

```
date    CPU.Percentage.Maximum  AverageUtil
4/1/2015 0:00   26.92   27.28794872
4/1/2015 1:00   27.04   27.28794872
4/1/2015 2:00   26.89   27.28794872
4/1/2015 3:00   25.555  27.28794872
4/1/2015 4:00   29.78   27.28794872
4/1/2015 5:00   28.035  27.28794872
4/1/2015 6:00   24.86   27.28794872
4/1/2015 7:00   26.61   27.28794872
4/1/2015 8:00   27.13   27.28794872
4/1/2015 9:00   26.48   27.28794872
4/1/2015 10:00  27.135  27.28794872
4/1/2015 11:00  28.14   27.28794872
4/1/2015 12:00  26.88   27.28794872
4/1/2015 13:00  28.3    27.28794872
4/1/2015 14:00  25.965  27.28794872
4/1/2015 15:00  27.66   27.28794872
4/1/2015 16:00  28.65   27.28794872
4/1/2015 17:00  26.43   27.28794872
4/1/2015 18:00  28.95   27.28794872
4/1/2015 19:00  28.535  27.28794872
4/1/2015 20:00  81.92   84.47125
4/1/2015 21:00  81.005  84.47125
4/1/2015 22:00  88.675  84.47125
4/1/2015 23:00  86.285  84.47125
4/2/2015 0:00   28.87   27.07410256
```

I have to find out the typical timings when the CPU utilisation is high,say above 75%.When i plotted the $date against the $Cpu percent maximimum on the whole dataset ,i was able to find a trend.The cpu utilisation goes high at the end of the day(21:00->23:00).How can i report this statistic in R.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to report from this data set?  I think the graph you currently have actually does a decent job of showing the spike in CPU usage at the end of each day.

Comment: Yes.I am trying to get that information into a tabular form.

Answer (score 0):

So long as your `date` data is actually a time/date format, you should be able to simply subset, `format` to extract the hour (`%H`) and `table` the results:

```
dat$date <- as.POSIXct(dat$date, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
table(format(dat$date[dat$CPU.Percentage.Maximum > 75],"%H"))

#20 21 22 23 
# 1  1  1  1
```